# Cant add ChangeListener to JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, actionlistener, jspinner

This may be a very simple question but I have an `AbstractTable` and in one of my columns I am trying to add a `ChangeListener` but it's giving me an error the error is:

```
The method actionListener(ChangeListener) in the type JSpinner is not applicable 
    for the arguments (new ChangeListener(){})
```

Here is my code where I am trying to add the `JSpinner` in the column:

```
}else if (col == 4){
Date today = new Date();        //Creates new default date (Todays Date)
final JSpinner Spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel(today, null, null, Calendar.MONTH)); // Creates Date Spinner
Spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {     //Error Here 
      @Override
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // handle click
      }
    });
value = Spinner;
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything technically wrong with your syntax. I am able to use it okay on my end.

Comment: Thankyou i wasnt sure were to look

Comment: You example snippet compiles for me

Comment: @CanadianDavid Im not sure i thought i was doing it right but for some reason im getting an error it works with a button just not with a spinner

Comment: @user3732179 What is the problem/message? Maybe you have a wrong ChnageListener imported, you have to import `javax.swing.event.ChangeListener`

Comment: wow so its just me wtf maybe its eclipse

Comment: @Jens yeap thanks mate that was it u legend Should i delete this question now? or do i leave it up?

Comment: @user3732179 Leave it. I have added my comment as an Answer. Fell free to upvote or accept it if it has helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a wrong ChnageListener imported, you have to import `javax.swing.event.ChangeListener`